# How to setup hd wallet using mnemonics with bitcoin-core?

Tags: bitcoin-core, mnemonic-seed

I'm currently learning Bitcoin wallets using Bitcoin Core, and I need some guidance and help especially when it comes to mnemonics and hd seeds.

This is what I have read about mnemonics and seeds: [bip-0039](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki)

**Creating wallet**

I can create new wallet using the ***createWallet*** command. This wallet has hd seed set automatically.

1. As I understand there is no way to restore mnemonic for such a wallet and the only way to restore it later is to backup hd seed from the file generated by the ***dumpWallet*** command?
2. If I want to be able to use mnemonic I need to generate it myself, transform to hd seed, and then set it using the ***sethdseed*** command? Bitcoin Core does not provide any command line tools to do this, and I need to use external tools for this?

**HD seed generation**

There are multiple tools to generate mnemonics and hd seeds: [Online](https://iancoleman.io/bip39/) or command line tools like [Bitcoin Explorer](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-explorer).

Both these tools for mnemonic: *rival hurdle address inspire tenant almost turkey safe asset step lab boy*
generate seed: *020b67fd929e0eb9f963443138057ceec0d62601d69b4b2327c00d74f0fd1862d164c53d49227d9dadedbbec305236bc2149d9a5267aa7c5aa004235c3c66c29*

The problem I have is that this generated seed is not accepted by ***sethdseed*** command. Apparently it is not hd seed.

3. How to transform this calculated seed to hd seed accepted by ***sethdseed*** command?
4. What are the best practices for generating mnemonics and hd seed completely offline?

Thanks and hope this will help someone in the future.

Comment: @Raghav Sood that explains partially my 3rd question, but I still don't have any idea how to transform mnemonic to hd seed accepted by Bitcoin Core. And there are other questions. But this thread is useful. Thank you.

Comment: You can't. They're two incompatible seed types

Comment: You should split up your other, unrelated questions into separate questions - this site isn't really designed for multiple independent questions in a single post

Comment: hi @Jubert. have you figured out something for your 4th question? what are the best practices for generating mnemonics and hd seed offline?